# Stencil Products Per Category Page Suddenly Ignored by Backend

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a Stencil theme in production that suddenly stopped working. Any given category page shows one product versus the 12 requested. 
theme_settings.categorypage_products_per_page is sent to server and 1 product is returned. The rest are paginated. Strangly, I have confirmed this issue with a fresh clone of the BigCommerce repository and stock Stencil code. Has anyone else seen this issue or know of a work around? Is it something hardset on our backend?

Comment: It's a bug we are working on addressing.

Comment: @Alyss Roger, that. Thanks.

Comment: @Alyss is there any work around for this for this? This is a pretty serious issue the usable of our site.

Comment: I do not know of a workaround, but a fix is being rolled out now.

Comment: I see the results of fix action to JIRA #MERC-670. Category object now batches correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This was a temporary issue on BigCommerce's end. It has sense been resolved as mentioned in the comments of the question.